# Is it okay to use "Thank you" in both body and closing of an email?

Tags: email

I want to send this email.

```
Hi xxx,

It is duly noted. Thank you.

Thank you,
xxx
```

Is this correct? Is it okay to use thank you twice like that?

Comment: That's a matter of style (and opinion). In principle the answer is that it's fine. You probably wouldn't want to use it twice in such quick succession as in your example, though. Vary it a bit by changing the signoff to "Thanks again" or (if greater formality is needed) "Once again, thank you very much", or by changing the body of the message to say "I'm very grateful for your assistance".

Comment: Backticks is meant for code, not for quotations. When you have the time, could you please fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not seriously wrong, but it seems a bit unnecessary.

You don't need a sign off in such a short email, so if it worries you just delete the second "thank you", or replace it by "Yours", or "Best regards" or similar.